# Add USB space in conky

Tags: arch-linux, path, xfce, conky

I'm setting conky and I'd like to add the usb space, I use:

```
$font${color DimGray}/ $alignc ${fs_used /} / ${fs_size /} $alignr ${fs_free_perc /}%
${fs_bar /}
```

for the full hdd, what should I write as path for USB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
${fs_used /media/Name_You_See} / ${fs_size /media/Name_You_See}
```

Or, if you use `udisks2`:

```
${fs_used /run/media/User/Name_You_See} / ${fs_size /run/media/User/Name_You_See}
```

Also consider `${if_existing /media/Name_You_See}` to check if path exists (which means it's mounted, not accurate but useful)

Comment: But I had lots of bugs :\ the solution however is correct

Comment: @AlessioMTX you could create a script to show all of them with `execpi`, but what's the bug?

Comment: The space of USB and sometimes don't read USB